# ERROR: Preparation failed: exec: "docker-machine": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: redhat, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-machine, podman, redhat-containers

I'm new to Gitlab and trying to setup some pipelines with executor docker+machine on RHEL/ Red Hat servers.

Since RHEL uses Podman containers so I am trying to use the same and while running the pipeline I am getting docker-machine exactable path not found in $PATH.

Here is my runner config

```
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  listen_address = "[::]:8092"
  advertise_address = "runner-host-name.tld:8093"
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Test"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  id = ****
  token = *****
  token_obtained_at = 2023-11-30T16:07:24Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker+machine"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    host = "/run/user/1966622/podman/podman.sock"
    tls_verify = false
    image = "python:3.9"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/data/gitlab-runner/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 0
    IdleScaleFactor = 0.0
    IdleCountMin = 0
    MachineDriver = "docker"
    MachineName = "%sTest"
    MachineOptions = ['green-4.saas-linux-medium-amd64.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default','green-3.saas-linux-medium-amd64.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default']
```

- Running podman machine manually by using command podman machine inti
- got error Error: exec: "qemu-system-x86_64": executable file not found in $PATH
- according to docs seems like qemu is only meant for mac but still gave tried on install on RHEL which didn't helped much

-Tried playing around the $PATH var, nothing worked as such